# Where can I find H2 JDBC driver?

Tags: drivers, database, h2

http://www.h2database.com/html/download.html I don't see it on this website. Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Dump this in your classpath: http://www.h2database.com/automated/h2-latest.jar

And then call

> Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");

That should do it.

Answer (score 8):

Go to the downloads page of the H2 website as you did. Download the INSTALLATION file for H2 and install it. Then, go to the folder where you installed it. The path to that folder (on a windows pc) should be C:\Program Files (x86)\H2\bin
There will be a jar file there which looks like h2-some version number.jar. That is your driver. Bin means binary and that is usually the place where i look for any jar file.

Comment: The questioner said he couldn't find the driver on the downloads page.

Comment: @Flup - You may have overlooked the fact that my answer guides the OP to the downloads page and then gets him the jar also. If you do what my answer says, then you will get the latest version of  the file that slotishtype gave in his link. I actually checked the two files.

Comment: @Flup - Please up vote my answer. Looks like my score of 1 point affected your judgement. We all begin at 1 don't we ?

Comment: You've edited your post since I downvoted it which has made it much more helpful, so I'll remove my downvote -- thanks :)

Comment: @Flup - The content of my post is essentially the same. Only a word or two were changed.

Answer (score 8):

Any downloaded `.jar` file in the `Jar File` section on `Downloads` page is the JDBC driver itself, e.g.: `h2-1.4.188.jar`

Comment: This is a great answer.  None of the other answers actually mention the "Jar File" section of the downloads page, nor do they explain that the files in that section are in fact the drivers the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm saddened that people still recommended (even *6* years ago) direct jar usage, instead of promoting maven/gradle/whatever build automation tool. From the downloads page maven section you can get maven URL for direct download, and translate it to your build tool's format. Below is its maven interpretation:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.200</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @ThachVan explained, the H2 jar file is the JDBC driver itself. Get it from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2

Comment: Instead of copying another answer, upvote it.

Comment: @Toto Of course I upvoted that. The link to the file may be useful, however. That includes both the option to get the jar file as well as getting the Maven/Gradle/... coordinates